# How to get VS Code to output the line number of errors while running a Node.js program from Run menu?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am running a JavaScript program (Node.js) from VS Code with `Ctrl+F5` or `F5` (`Run Without Debugging` or `Start Debugging`), and execution stops because of an error in my code. The `DEBUG CONSOLE` of VS Code shows me the error and the name of the affected source file, but not the line number where the error occurred in the source file. It says instead **No debugger available, can not send 'variables'**.

E.g. see the error at line 7 of the program in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot 1]

How can I get VS Code to show me the line number where an error has occurred, after running the program from the `Run` menu?

I noticed that I can have it if I run my program from the VS Code `TERMINAL` instead. See this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: any solution for this?